# PUT and DELETE methods not called in NodeJS Express Angular 2 app

Tags: node.js, express, http-delete, http-put

I have this app with Express backend:

`server.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var methodOverride = require('method-override')
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var mysql = require('mysql');
...
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
...
app.route('/api/lessons').get((req, res) => {
    con.query('SELECT * FROM lesson', (err, rows) => {
        if (err)
            res.send(JSON.stringify({ "status": 500, "error": err, "response": null }));
        else
            res.send(JSON.stringify({ "status": 200, "error": null, "response": rows }));
    });
});
...
app.route('/api/lessons/:lessonId').put(function (req, res) {
    console.log("Backend PUT");
    var lessonId = req.param('lessonId');
    con.query('UPDATE lesson SET title=?, body=?, level_id=? WHERE id=?', [req.body.title, req.body.body, req.body.level_id, lessonId], (err, rows) => {
        if (err)
            res.send(JSON.stringify({ "status": 500, "error": err, "response": null }));
        else
            res.send(JSON.stringify({ "status": 200, "error": null, "response": rows }));
    });
});
...
app.route('/api/lessons/:lessonId').delete((req, res) => {
    console.log("Backend DELETE");
    var lessonId = req.param('lessonId');
    con.query('DELETE FROM lesson WHERE id=?', [lessonId], (err, rows) => {
        if (err)
            res.send(JSON.stringify({ "status": 500, "error": err, "response": null }));
        else
            res.send(JSON.stringify({ "status": 200, "error": null, "response": rows }));
    });
});
```

Angular service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Configuration } from '../../app.constants';

@Injectable()
export class LessonService {
  private restUrl: string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.restUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/lessons/';
  }

  public getAll() {
    return this.http.get(this.restUrl);
  }

  public getOne(id: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.restUrl + id);
  }

  public getAllForLevel(id: number) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/lessons-for-level/' + id);
  }
...
  public update(id: number, level: any) {
    console.log(this.restUrl+id);
    return this.http.put(this.restUrl + id, level);
  }

  public delete(id: number) {
    console.log("DELETE: " + this.restUrl + id);
    return this.http.delete(this.restUrl + id);
  }
...
}
```

All the GET methods are working correctly, but not the PUT or the DELETE method. With `console.log`'s I concluded that the service methods `update` and `delete` are getting called from the frontend, but the REST endpoints (in `server.js`) are never called. There are no error messages at all.

What could be the problem?

**Edits**: Besides the PUT method, the DELETE is also not getting called. I've edited the title and the question. Also I've added `console.log`s in the `update` and `delete` methods so I can check what URL is being called, and it is `http://localhost:8000/api/lessons/2` (for example), so it's correct. I've tried calling that URL via Postman both for PUT and DELETE and it works correctly, it changed or deleted the relevant entry in the DB. So as it looks to me, the only problem is the lack of communication between frontend and backend.

Comment: If front-end is calling properly then there should be something logged at back-end that what end-point is hitting your server, did you check that?

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon I've checked, there is nothing. No error message, and even the console.log that I've put into the backend is not called. It looks as if the REST endpoint is not reached at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution.

**tl;dr:**
I didn't put the `.subscribe` in the place where I call the `update` method.

**Long version:**
When I call various `get` methods from my service, I do it like this:

```
this.lessonService.getAllForLevel(this.levelId).subscribe(data => this.lessons = data['response']);
```

However, I thought that I can call my `update` method like this:

```
this.lessonService.update(this.lessonId, this.lesson);
```

...because I thought there was nothing interesting that I should subscribe to.

However, when I changed the call to this:

```
this.lessonService.update(this.lessonId, this.lesson).subscribe(data => console.dir(data));
```

...it worked correctly (don't mind the `console.dir` part, I just wanted to put something in the `subscribe` part so it would work).